# Is "but not for multipe types" or other words wrong in my sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I wrote one sentence as follows.

> "For academic research, I found that almost all of the existing indexes for queries on large graphs work well for one type of query but not for multiple types. As the graphs grow in sizes, building and storing multiple types of index for different queries will greatly reduce the query performance of graph database. "

I am not sure if there are some errors in my sentence, such as "but not for multiple types" or other words. So may I ask that can you help me indicate any errors existed in my sentence?

Comment: Proofreading questions are [off-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: OK, I am sorry for that. And I have made my question more specific.